# dplyr select column using string and apply base function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Suppose a mathematical operation that I need to do is specified as a character vector

```
math.operation <- 'mean' # this could be mean, sum or length
```

I want to do apply this `math.operation` on a column whose name is also provided as a string in dplyr

```
my.column <- 'col1'
 
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                  col1 = 1:16,
                  col2 = 16:1)
```

I first selected the column based on `my.column` and then added back my grouping variable which is `id` and then tried to do the operation by group

```
dat %>% dplyr::select(contains(my.column)) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(id = dat$id) %>%
dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(match.fun(math.operation)(my.column))
```

I am stuck in the last line which is producing NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
You can use `do.call` with `!! sym()`. Note that I deleted your first `select` and `mutate` calls, since they seem to be redundant for this example.

**Option 2**
Instead of `do.call` you could use `call`, here you would not need to wrap the argument in `list()`, but then you would need to use `eval`, so the statement is not really shorter.

**Option 3**
A third option is to use your approach with `match.fun` and `!! sym()` which was missing in your example. However, I think `do.call` is more straightforward.

**Option 4**
Finally you could use `eval(parse(...))`, but the first way using `do.call` and `!! sym()` is preferable.

```r
library(dplyr)

math.operation <- 'mean' # this could be mean, sum or length

my.column <- 'col1'

dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                  col1 = 1:16,
                  col2 = 16:1)
# Option 1
dat %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(newvar = do.call(math.operation, list(!! sym(my.column))))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id newvar
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    2.5
#> 2     2    6.5
#> 3     3   10.5
#> 4     4   14.5

# Option 2
dat %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(newvar = eval(call(math.operation, !! sym(my.column))))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id newvar
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    2.5
#> 2     2    6.5
#> 3     3   10.5
#> 4     4   14.5

# Option 3
dat %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(newvar = match.fun(math.operation)(!! sym(my.column)))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id newvar
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    2.5
#> 2     2    6.5
#> 3     3   10.5
#> 4     4   14.5

# Option 4
dat %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(newvar = eval(parse(text = paste0(math.operation, "(", my.column , ")"))))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      id newvar
#>   <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1    2.5
#> 2     2    6.5
#> 3     3   10.5
#> 4     4   14.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>